# can we rejoin a group call in `Quickblox` that we missed?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have some queries in the `group video calling in Quickblox`.

- p1 starts a group call with p2, p3, p4 & p5
- only p2,p3 picked up the call and p4 & p5 missed it
- can p4,p5 know `if the call is still in progress` for that group or not.
- if yes, `can they rejoin the group call in between?`
- if they can rejoin, how?
- can you provide some assistance or link about the `documentation about it?`

i was not able to find answers about these questions, as the `official documentation do not provide solid information about these things`. I droped a question to there team as well about the same, but `no reply from there side`.

Any assistance about the topic will be helpfull, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular calls in quick blox are implemented as a peer to peer calls. You can not join the session once its gone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Conference video calls are suitable for your need, but this feature available only for enterprise clients. More info about Conference video calls [there](https://quickblox.com/developers/EnterpriseFeatures).